# Wordpress Custom block gutenberg translation

Tags: wordpress, internationalization, gutenberg-blocks

I'm facing an issue with translating my Gutenberg block in WordPress. I have followed the recommended practices for internationalization, but the translations are not being applied correctly.

Here are the relevant details of my implementation:

I have defined the translation function __() in my JavaScript files and used it to wrap the texts that need to be translated.
Example:
`{ __('Nez', 'product-details') }`

In my PHP file, I have registered the block type and set the translations using the wp_set_script_translations() function. I have generated the corresponding .po and .mo files for my desired language and placed them in the /languages directory.

```
function block_set_translations() {
    wp_set_script_translations( 'product-details-editor-script', 'product-details', __DIR__ . '/languages' );
}

add_action( 'init', 'block_set_translations' );
```

In my index.js I defined the textdomain inside registerBlockType:
`textdomain: "bmg-product-details",`

I have checked that the domain and text strings in my JavaScript files match the domain and text strings in my .po file. Then I generated json files.

I have also made sure that my WordPress environment is properly configured for translations, including loading the text domain and specifying the path to the translation files.

Desspite following these steps, the tranlations are not being applied to the Gutenberg block. The default text is displayed instead of the translated strings.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it. Thank you in advance for your help!